# Is this the most idiomatic way to convert matrix into dataset?

Tags: matrix, import, dataset

Is this the most idiomatic way to convert matrix into dataset? (for Mathematica 10 or higher)

I was kind of hoping this would work:

```
Dataset[{{"a", "b", "c"}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}]
```

but it did not, [instead I had to use this trick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114081/create-a-dataset-object-association-or-sparesarray-from-a-matrix), the 4th line is a pretty arcane incantation:

```
m = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}
data = Drop[m, 1]
columnNames = First[m]
as = AssociationThread[columnNames -> #] & /@ data
Dataset[as]
```

Is there no way around it? I would have expected [with guides like this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/PutDataInAGridWithTheFrontEnd.html) that imply Mathematica matrix/tables can be used in place of a spreadsheets, converting to a DataSet could be done in a single step (*with some sort of in memory equivalent to [SemanticImport](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SemanticImport.html) that received a matrix instead of a file name, a "SemanticImportMatrix" equivalent to [SemanticImportString](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SemanticImportString.html)*)

Is there anything like that?

Comment: `Dataset[AssociationThread[m[[1]] -> #] & /@ Rest[m]]` is a bit shorter but it probably does not appeal to you either. Notice that the input is a matrix; thus, you have to add the addition structure (column titles) by hand.

Comment: Currently, there is no better way to create a list of associations other than mapping `AssociationThread` over the matrix and I agree that this is a bit jarring. On the other hand: keep in mind that `Dataset` is not supposed to be a magical "turn everything into a nice data structure automatically" function: it's a wrapper that makes data easier to access and display (it also does some type checking in the background). Structuring your data is still a manual job. If a magic structuring function should be incorporated, it should be separate from `Dataset`, IMO.

Comment: CSV and Excel formats have good support for interpretting the data as a dataset with headers using the "Dataset" and "HeaderLines" options.. I realize you have the data already in M though. I have honestly done a `ImportString[ExportString[m, "CSV"], {"CSV", "Dataset"}, "HeaderLines" -> 1]` as a workaround before, which works for this example.